# How to measure CPU cores usage for a single process?

Tags: windows-7, windows, process, windows-server-2008-r2, cpu-usage

Is there a way to see which and how many cores are used by single process on Windows server 2008 R2?

I have tried Windows task manager and Process explorer but without any success.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  This isn't something a user normally needs to know.  A process will use as many threads as it was programmed to use.

Comment: I am trying to find out how many cores uses python.exe when I am seeding tiles in Mapproxy. But it is not important. Generally I just want to know if there is a way to see if the process is using one or more cores at the same time.